# image css js not loaded when using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Any help plz, Image js and css just not loaded after i use htaccess. I also tried many sample but it still not work.

My root folder is : newstest contains some folder

www > newstest > css folder, js folder,images folder, articles folder

In folder articles has index.php and .htaccess file.

linking file in index.php of articles folder:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

When I load index.php in articles folder without htaccess, All files(css,js,image..) it loaded. But when I use htaccess all files that link to index.php is not found.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?c=$1&id=$2
```

Values c & id are just past correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your lines like below:

```
<script src="/newstest/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/newstest/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And add this line to your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```